# Python histogram is located on the right side of exact solution

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am working on a project in thermal physics, and for that I need to compare a histogram with a smooth curve. My problem is that the histogram is placed to the right for the curve (the curve is consistent going though the upper left corner of the bars):

[image: Figure 1]

I want the curve to go though the middle of the top of the bars, like it should. It might looks like a trifle, but it really irritates me. I hope someone can help me!

The program looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#--Constants--
M = 20      # Jmax
N = 1000    # Number of J values
T = 50      # Actually T/theta_r

J1 = np.linspace(0,M,N)
J2 = np.linspace(0,M,M+1)

#--Calculate z--
def z(J):
    return(2*J+1)*np.exp(-J*(J+1)/T)

#--Plot--
width = .9                           #Width of columns
plt.bar(J2, z(J2), width=width)      #Plotting histogram
#plt.xticks(ind + width / 2, ind)     #Replacing the indexes under the columns
plt.plot(J1,z(J1),'-r', linewidth=2)
SZ={'size':'16'}
plt.title('Different terms $z(j)$ plotted as function of $j$',**SZ)
plt.xlabel('$j$',**SZ)
plt.ylabel('$z(j)$',**SZ)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I guess this "problem" is connected to the way the bars are placed! Increase the granularity and plot more bars and you will see, that the whole picures changes, e.g. try `width = .7`? For further explanation: The data, that is used to plot one single bar is not evenly distributed; depending on the "internal" peaks of the data in that `.9`-range of points, the curve your are plotting is not perfectly in the middle of the bar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to [`plt.bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) specifies the positions of the *left-hand edges* for each bar. To make the *centre* of each bar to align with your plot of `z(J2)` you need to offset the positions of the edges by minus half the bar width:

```
plt.bar(J2 - 0.5 * width, z(J2), width=width)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the keyword option `align='center'` which will interpret `J2` as the coordinates of the bar centers instead of left edges.